# Deserializing a list of jsons

Tags: apex, json, list, deserialize

I am trying to deserialize a list of jsons.

If I have only one json like so `'{"apple":"green"}'` I can parse it using `JSON.deserializeUntyped`:

```
Map<String, Object> input = (Map<String, Object>)JSON.deserializeUntyped('{"apple":"green"}');
```

However in my case I want to parse `'[{"apple":"green"},{"banana":"yellow"}]'`.

I tried using:

```
List<Map<String, Object>> input = (List<Map<String, Object>>)JSON.deserializeUntyped('[{"apple":"green"},{"banana":""}]');
```

However that throws a TypeException: `Invalid conversion from runtime type List<ANY> to List<Map<String,ANY>>`.

I can't make a class to parse this list of jsons as I don't know how long the list will be. I also don't know what the values will be.

What I do know is that it will be `List<Map<String,String>>`. But I can't get to parse it.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Apex's type system is weird. Perhaps someone wiser than me can explicate the underlying principle or limiting case here in terms of the language grammar in  more detail, but I will only try to sketch it!

You can deserialize this JSON using `JSON.deserializeUntyped()`; you just have to deserialize it as an almost completely generic type: `List<Object>`. The JSON parser, when using `deserializeUntyped()`, doesn't have any information about the types of the elements of the outermost container - they could be Maps, Lists, or a heterogenous suite, and their own elements' types are also undefined.

Once the deserialization has been performed, you can cast the items themselves to their actual underlying types and take action on them:

```
List<Object> input = (List<Object>)JSON.deserializeUntyped('[{"apple":"green"},{"banana":""}]');

System.debug(input);

for (Object o : input) {
    System.debug((Map<String, Object>)o);
}
```

This gets you pretty much the log that you expect:

> 16:08:26:004 USER_DEBUG [5]|DEBUG|({apple=green}, {banana=})
>
> 16:08:26:004 USER_DEBUG [3]|DEBUG|{apple=green}
>
> 16:08:26:004 USER_DEBUG [3]|DEBUG|{banana=}

Naturally, you'll get a runtime exception if the actual type of one of the elements doesn't match your cast.

If you'd rather fully specify the type, you can do that too. This makes a sort of promise to the compiler about the types of the outermost collection's constituent members (a promise that the JSON must bear out!):

```
List<Map<String, String>> input = (List<Map<String, String>>)JSON.deserialize('[{"apple":"green"},{"banana":""}]', List<Map<String, String>>.class);
System.debug(input);
for (Object o : input) {
    System.debug((Map<String, Object>)o);
}
```

and you'll get the same debug output.

The `.class` construct is documented under [`System.Type`](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_methods_system_type.htm#apex_methods_system_type). It gets you a reference to the `Type` object corresponding to that class.

Comment: Thank you, this is awesome! I did try your second suggestion but did not put the `.class` at the end. What does that `.class` stand for? Where can I read about it?

Comment: `.class` is getting you a reference to the class corresponding to the type `List<Map<String, String>>`.  There's a handful of places you use that in Apex, including `Test.setMock()`, but it's relatively uncommon because Apex doesn't have much runtime reflection support. I'm not sure where it's documented. I'll take a look.

Comment: See my edit for a doc link.

Comment: Super useful, thanks for sharing and thanks for responding!

Comment: @DavidReed Man, you are a pro. I am learning a lot from posts like this. Keep up the good work.